# Указать тип движения в Gmaps используя iFrame

Tags: google-maps-api, iframe

Нужно показать статический маршрут движения груза. Сама идея работает, но показывает несколько вариантов движения: на машине, самолете и поезд. Необходимо явно указать тип "на автомобиле".

```
<iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Moskow+Omsk&mode=driving&output=embed" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

`mode` -  не работает для данного типа запроса, но он явно должен быть. не могу найти в документации полный список параметров для `iframe` 
Какой параметр отвечает за это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
&mode=driving
```

Только это не работает для всех типов